# How to duplicate the mysql row on PreUpdate event

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

I have a requirement to keep the history of any change happening on the one of my table. I have two table with exactly same schema, one with an additional id  column. I am trying to duplicate the record if a PreUpdate event is fired by JPA. I was able to get the event. But the problem is I am not getting the fresh record from DB, since already the same record is being edited.

```
@PreUpdate
    public void preUpdate(POItem item) {
        try{
            if(dao == null){
                AutowireHelper.getInstance().autowire(this,this.dao);
            }

            POItem fresh = dao.find(POItem.class,item.getId());

            logger.info("UPDATED");
            logger.info(item.toString());

            logger.info("CURRENT");
            logger.info(fresh.toString());

        }catch (Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I could able to see both current and updated is holding same object, with the change that is going to commit.

What is the way here to get the a fresh record from the sql table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implementing Auditing is not an easy task. My suggestion is not to implement by yourself.

If you are using hibernate, then: 
Fortunately there is a framework for entity auditing called Hibernate Envers. All that is required is some xml configuration and marking entities with audited annotation.

Even there is Spring data jpa support to retrieve audit versions.
Following are some useful links:
Hibernate envers page: http://hibernate.org/orm/envers/
Reference Implementation: http://hantsy.blogspot.in/2013/11/auditing-with-hibernate-envers.html

Comment: Thanks for looking into this, anyway let me see if I can use enverse effectively for situation, I will update if I am successful.

Comment: Thanks again, thats  better approach. I got it working.